# Count The Amount Of Data In An Array Including SOME Null

Tags: java

I'm coding in java and I need to create a function that returns the number of data objects that are currently in an ArrayList. At the moment I have this:

> ```
>   int count = 0;
>     for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
>     { 
>         if (data[i] != null)
>         {
>             count ++;
>         }
>     }
>     return count;
> ```

But the problem is that an array list that includes null data is acceptable, and I have to count their null data towards this counter. How do I include the null data that's in the middle of this array, and not the null data that's not supposed to be counted for?

For example, I have some tester code that adds (8),null,null,(23),(25) to the array, and this function should return 5 when the initial array size is 10.

Comment: Are they in an `Array`? Or an `ArrayList`? You question goes back and forth...

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're using a regular array (your question is somewhat ambiguous about this). Traverse through the array backwards until you find a non-null element:

```
public static int count(Object[] a) {
    int i = a.length - 1;
    for (; i >= 0 ; i--)
        if (a[i] != null)
            break;
    return i + 1;
}
```

You could also have

```
public static <T> int count(T[] a) {
    int i = a.length - 1;
    for (; i >= 0 ; i--)
        if (a[i] != null)
            break;
    return i + 1;
}
```

---

Let's test it out, using an example analogous to the one you provided:

```
Object[] a = new Object[10];
a[0] = new Object();
a[3] = new Object();
a[4] = new Object();
System.out.println(count(a));
```

Output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need two separate counters. The first one will count normally. The second one starts counting when you find `null` data. Then when you find a non-null data, just add the second counter to the first one and continue counting with the first counter until you find a null again.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (data[i] != null || count > 0)
        count += 1;
return count;
```

At least that's how I understood your requirements - count nulls, except for trailing nulls.

But maybe that's not actually what you meant?

#### Edit

Unless you're actually using `ArrayList` (as Jon was asking), where `.size()` is different from *capacity* and will count all added elements (including nulls). You can't actually even get the capacity from an `ArrayList`.